# Solidworks Weldment Profile Configuration Selecting

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

I want to use tube templates in my assembly. I configured a `.sldlfp` file in my weldment templates.

I can configure height of part but not tube size. I have a userform for entering height and selecting tube size.

Should I use [`IStructuralMemberFeatureData`](https://help.solidworks.com/2017/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IStructuralMemberFeatureData%7EConfigurationName.html)?

Here is the combobox I have same name in my weldment templates.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN15"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN20"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN25"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN32"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN40"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN50"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN65"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "DN80"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with multiple tube templates

```
With Me.ComboBox1
            .AddItem "1/2''   Çap 21,3 DN15"
            .AddItem "3/4''   Çap 26,9 DN20"
            .AddItem "1''     Çap 33,7 DN25"
        End With
    
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then
        Dim Weldment As String
        Weldment = "C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\lang\turkish\weldment profiles\iso\pipe\21.3 x 2.3.sldlfp"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1 Then
        Weldment = "C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\lang\turkish\weldment profiles\iso\pipe\26.9 x 3.2.sldlfp"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2 Then
        Weldment = "C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\lang\turkish\weldment profiles\iso\pipe\33.7 x 4.0.sldlfp"
    End If
    Set myFeature = swModel.FeatureManager.InsertStructuralWeldment4(Weldment, 1, True, (vGroups))
```